# Generating MD5 Signature in PHP

Tags: php, md5, digital-signature

I have to submit an array via cURL in PHP, and one of the item in the array must be a signature generated with MD5 on a concatenation of array items and a public key:

```
// public key
$key = '4d7894219f3d28a6fbb8c415779dfffc';

// payload; each item was initialized
$vars = array(
    'id'=>$id,
    'name'=>$name,
    'phone'=>$phone,
    'email'=>$email,
    'subject'=>$subject,
    'notes'=>$notes,
    'time'=>date('Y-m-d H:m:s'),
);

// Now create a HTTP query with the items of the array
$caesar = '';
foreach ($vars as $key2 => $value) {
    $caesar = $caesar . $key2 . '=' . $value . '&';
}
unset($key2);
unset($value);
$caesar = substr($caesar, 0, -1);

// Concatenate the string from step 2 and $key (string then $key)
$caesar = $caesar . $key;

//MD5
$signature = md5($caesar);
```

Later I add the sig to the array and use cURL to transfer the array. But the server keeps returning "invalid signature". I don't see what is wrong. Please help me to identify the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I can't see how this would work.  You're embedding the current time into the data, which will be different for every execution of the script, making a different signature each time.

Comment: `$key` is appended to the query string without a name, maybe that's the problem? maybe you meant something like `$caesar .= "key=$key"`?

Comment: as for $key, it's not part of the query. It's just used for MD5

Comment: I fixed the "time" field but it's not working still. I put the string "2012-02-07 10:43:22".

Comment: What are you doing with `$signature` once you've computed it?  Are there any public docs on this web service?